# Number sort using Min, Max and Variables

Tags: variables, python-3.x, max, min

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a program that will take 3 random numbers X Y and Z and will sort them into ascending order X being the lowest and Z the highest using Min, Max functions and a Variable (tmp)

I know that there is a particular strategy that I need to use that effects the (X,Y) pair first then (Y,Z) then (X,Y) again but I can't grasp the logic.

The closest I have got so far is...

```
y=min(y,z)
x=min(x,y) 
tmp=max(y,z) 
z=tmp 
tmp=max(x,y) 
y=tmp 
x=min(x,y) 
tmp=max(x,y) 
y=tmp
```

I've tried so many different combinations but it seems that the problem is UNSOLVABLE can anybody else help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get sort the X,Y Pair first

```
tmp=min(x,y)
y=max(x,y)
x=tmp
```

Then sort the Y,Z pair

```
tmp = min(y,z)
z=max(y,z)
y=tmp
```

Then, resort the X,Y pair (in case the original Z was the lowest value...

```
tmp=min(x,y)
y=max(x,y)
x=tmp
```

If the commands you have mentioned are the only ones available on the website, and you can only use each one once try:

```
# Sort X,Y pair
tmp=max(x,y) 
x=min(x,y) 
y=tmp 

# Sort Y,Z pair
tmp=max(y,z) 
y=min(y,z)
z=tmp 

# Sort X,Y pair again.
tmp=max(x,y) 
x=min(x,y) 
y=tmp
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you are over righting your variables. Or are you trying to solve some homework with the restriction to only use min() and max() functions?

What about using a list?

```
tmp = [x, y, z]
tmp.sort()
x, y, z = tmp
```

Comment: I'm a teacher and I am testing a website that I think may be suitable for my pupils however one of the activities on there I am unable to solve myself which is the one above. All of the statements you can see above are what I HAVE to use. (It's a drag and drop type exercise) so I need to put the statements in the correct order for the program to then display X, Y and Z in ascending order. The website gives me the hint that I need to do something with (X,Y) then (Y,Z) then (X,Y) again but I can't figure it out. Any Idea?

Comment: Ah, OK! Maybe you should clarify your question and add the restrictions.