# Sorting int variables using a function

Tags: python

I want to sort 3 int's into ascending order using a python function. i gave it a few tries but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
s = int(input())
m = int(input())
l = int(input())
temp = 0
def sortasc(x,y):
    if x > y:
        temp = y
        y = x
        x = temp
sortasc(s,m)
sortasc(m,l)
sortasc(s,m)
print(s,m,l)
```

Comment: your variables are local to the function. thus your function has no effect. You should read about global and local variables in python.

Comment: In Python arguments are passed by value. Any reassignment you do to them, will not be reflected to the caller.

Comment: @trincot how would i go about making them re-assign the global variables

Comment: @PaulRooney we are not allowed to use lists for these questions

Comment: if you are being taught to use global variables, its not the right way. It will be hard to implement your function as you will be changing different globals depending on what you are passing in. Are you allowed to use tuples?

Comment: @PaulRooney no, only really simple stuff for now

Comment: It will be far easier to return tuples than to try to alter globals which are passed in to a function. The answer below is using tuples.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115046/number-sort-using-min-max-and-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number sort using Min, Max and Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115046/number-sort-using-min-max-and-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument variables are modified in the function, but this is not reflected to the caller which is looking at the global variables and has no access to the function's local variables.

One way of solving this, is making your function return the correct values (in correct order):

```
s = int(input())
m = int(input())
l = int(input())

def sortasc(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return y,x
    return x,y

s,m = sortasc(s,m)
m,l = sortasc(m,l)
s,m = sortasc(s,m)
print(s,m,l)
```

Test it on: [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/4)

Or, you can pass in *references* to the two values, via a list:

```
s = int(input())
m = int(input())
l = int(input())

def sortasc(lst, i, j):
    if lst[i] > lst[j]:
        lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

lst = [s, m, l]
sortasc(lst, 0, 1)
sortasc(lst, 1, 2)
sortasc(lst, 0, 1)
print(lst[0], lst[1], lst[2])
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/5)

Comment: when using `list` why not just do `lst.sort()`

Comment: @NishanthMatha I think you should probably be asking the OP that.

Comment: @PaulRooney OP has already said he doesn't want to use `list` in his comments, so directing the question to him would be redundant!

Comment: It's obviously being done for learning purposes. We both know we'd use sort but the OP wants to learn about sorting.